# Upgrading a solution C++ from VS2005 to VS2012 have an error LNK1181

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

i'm upgrading a C++ solution with some dll projects and one exe console shell, actually the project build in the Visual Studio 2005, this project is very old and very sensible. This work with all of my dispositives to communicate with his APIs, and send his events to my app in C#. Today i received the flag to start upgrading the project to Visual Studio 2012, but after the upgrade all of my projects receive the LNK 1181 error, don't find the nameproject.res file, but i don't have in any of the projects a .res file, happen's a .rc and no one of 25 projects build.

```
Error   6   error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'D:\Projects\DeviceManager\Branches\DSR865-BRB_DeviceManager\C-Fontes\tmp\DeviceManagerClassLibrary\Release\DeviceManagerClassLibrary.res'
```

I don't know what i can do to make these projects build!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile the .rc file first, before linking.

http://www.winasm.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=154

Comment: I have build the RC, but in the answer in winasm the guy speek to Assemble the RC, i'm not see in visual studio 2012 a button or option to assemble. I have build the RC and after tryed build the project, but receive the same error.

Comment: Reading the output when i build the RC i see this `res = "D:\Projects\DeviceManager\Branches\DSR865-BRB_DeviceManager\C-Fontes\tmp\DeviceManagerClassLibrary\Release\\DeviceManagerClassLibrary.res"` Have a \\ when i trying compile, and this causes an error. Thanks @Dan, with your help i can see this!

Answer (score 0):

To correct the Issue I have to exclude the RC file from project and create a new RC file with version and importing all other things to the new RC. I don't know, but i think the VS 2005 RC file is not compatible with VS 2012. After i make this the project build and create the .res file.